# Tuples and nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x =[(34, 55), (1, 75), (5, 36), (1, 49), (1, 186), [(3, 47), (131, 167)], (7, 434)]

y= [(77, 98), (109, 183), (77, 108), (1, 49), (1, 185), [(45, 78), (45, 84)], (3, 429)]
```

I'd like to obtain the following from the above lists.

```
    q:34-55    h:77-98

    q:1-75     h:109-183

    q:5-36     h:77-108

    q:1-49     h:1-49

    q:1-186    h:1-185

    q:3-47     h:45-78    q:131-167    h:45, 84

    q:7-434    h:3-429
```

any suggestions on how to get it done? Thanks in advance

I tried the following:

```
 for i in x:
     if type(i) != list:
         print "q:%d-%d" % (i[0], i[1]) 
q:34-55
q:1-75
q:5-36
q:1-49
q:1-186
q:7-434
```

Comment: Can you be specific. You just need to print or you need to have them in another list?

Comment: What did you try so far? Basicly it should be able to be done with some loops

Comment: Thanks you all for responing...I want to write it to a file, as weel as print it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
x =[(34, 55), (1, 75), (5, 36), (1, 49), (1, 186), [(3, 47), (131, 167)], (7, 434)]
y= [(77, 98), (109, 183), (77, 108), (1, 49), (1, 185), [(45, 78), (45, 84)], (3, 429)]

tmpl = "\tq: {0}\th: {1}"

for q, h in zip(x, y):
    if isinstance(q, list):
        for q2, h2 in zip(q, h):
            print tmpl.format(q2, h2),
        print
    else:
        print tmpl.format(q, h)
```